# Coq inference behavior

Tags: types, coq, agda, dependent-type

I'm trying to write the following Agda snippet in Coq.

```
open import Data.Fin using (Fin; suc; zero)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; suc; zero)

thin : {n : ℕ} -> Fin (suc n) -> Fin n -> Fin (suc n)
thin zero    y       = suc y
thin (suc x) zero    = zero
thin (suc x) (suc y) = suc (thin x y)
```

I thought this could be straightforwardly translated to Coq as:

```
Inductive Fin : nat -> Type :=
  | fz {n : nat} : Fin (S n)
  | fs {n : nat} : Fin n -> Fin (S n).

Fixpoint thin {n : nat} (x : Fin (S n)) (y : Fin n) : Fin (S n) :=
  match x, y with
    | fz,      y' => fs y'
    | (fs x'), fz => fz
    | (fs x'), (fs y') => fs (thin x' y')
  end.
```

This, however, results in the following error:

```
Toplevel input, characters 171-173:
Error:
In environment
thin : forall n : nat, Fin (S n) -> Fin n -> Fin (S n)
n : nat
x : Fin (S n)
y : Fin n
n0 : nat
x' : Fin n0
n1 : nat
y' : Fin n1
The term "x'" has type "Fin n0" while it is expected to have type
 "Fin (S ?n1)".
```

I believe Coq should be able to figure out the implicit parameter `n` so I have no idea what is going on. I think I am unaware of a difference between the type systems of Agda and Coq since the former typechecks fine.

Comment: Pattern matching in Coq is not as powerful as in Agda. IIRC, you can help Coq by defining `Fin` by recursion. Try to translate [this](http://lpaste.net/162317).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When pattern matching with dependent types, Coq does not usually consider some essential relations between the variables in the context and the variables introduced in the branches.

The easiest solution is to define the function in proof mode, at least to understand what is going on.

This gives:

```
Fixpoint thin {n : nat} (x : Fin (S n)) (y : Fin n) : Fin (S n).
Proof.
  remember (S n) as n1. (* trick to keep the information when destructing *)
  destruct x; apply eq_add_S in Heqn1; subst n0.
  - apply fs. assumption.
  - destruct y.
    + apply fz.
    + apply fs. apply thin; assumption.
Defined. (* to create a transparent constant, as given by a classic Fixpoint *)
```

You can then print the value and read the lambda term to understand how to define it directly. This could give:

```
Fixpoint thin {n : nat} (x : Fin (S n)) (y : Fin n) : Fin (S n) :=
  match x as x0 in Fin k return k = S n -> Fin (S n) with
  | fz => fun _ => fs y
  | fs x' =>
      fun H => match y as y0 in Fin l return n = l -> Fin (S n) with
      | fz => fun _ => fz
      | fs y' => fun H' =>
          fs (eq_rec_r (fun x => Fin x)
                       (thin (eq_rec_r _
                                (eq_rec_r _ x' (eq_add_S _ _ (eq_sym H)))
                                (eq_sym H'))
                              y')
                       H')
      end eq_refl
  end eq_refl.
```

The `return` clauses of the pattern matchings is used to solve the problem presented above: they connect the variables introduced in the branches and the ones in the context. This is discussed more deeply here: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html.

Also note that this particular inductive type was discussed a few weeks ago on the coq-club mailing list. See https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2016-03/msg00206.html.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks! I should have finished Chlipala's book before actually trying to do stuff in Coq. One more question I have: is it considered bad practice to define functions in proof mode?

Comment: @cauliflower I don't really know. Usually, I do that to check the lambda term and write it myself. Anyway, I try to use mostly low-level tactics to create a readable lambda term. Tactics like `inversion` create

Comment: Tactics like `inversion` create non-natural terms and should be avoided. Maybe other users have stronger opinions on this particular subject.

Comment: @cauliflower I write functions in proof mode all the time.  A common idea is to use Coq's inference and tactical capabilities to synthesize terms in an automated manner.  However, this is not necessarily what the majority of users are used to.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick to a syntax fairly similar to Agda's, you can use Sozeau's [equations](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/) plugin. You'll be able to write:

```
Require Import Equations.

Inductive Fin : nat -> Type :=
  | fz {n : nat} : Fin (S n)
  | fs {n : nat} : Fin n -> Fin (S n).

Lemma FinO_elim : Fin O -> False.
Proof.
inversion 1.
Qed.

Equations thin {n : nat} (x : Fin (S n)) (y : Fin n) : Fin (S n)
:= thin {n:=O}     _      y      :=! y (* y is uninhabited *)
;  thin fz     y      := fs y
;  thin (fs x) fz     := fz
;  thin (fs x) (fs y) := fs (thin x y)
.

You can also remove the first dead-code clause which is automatically inferred.
```

Comment: What version do you use for Coq and for the plugin ? With `n` as an implicit argument, I have the strange error "Non-exhaustive pattern-matching".

Comment: I have coq 8.5~beta2 installed via opam and coq:equations 0.9~beta2. BTW, if you look closely at the type of `thin`, you'll see that `n` is an implicit argument. However equations seems to require all the implicit arguments to be made explicit when defining the function.

Comment: With Coq 8.5.dev and equations 8.5.dev, the same example does not work. I had seen that `n` was declared to be implicit, but this is exactly the problem. When `n` is not implicit (and added to the recursive call), the example is accepted.